# laravel - Google Analytics API data fetching based on profile

Tags: php, laravel, google-analytics

I am trying to build an app where the users will authenticate with their analytics accounts and depending on what analytics profile they choose the data for it will be fetched and shown in a line chart graph.

Thus far I've managed to do the authentication(thanks to a previous question I've found here on stackoverflow) and list the analytics profiles in a dropdown where the user can select any of them.

Now I'm stuck on finding a way for fetching the right data for the selected profile.

These 2 methods are the ones I'm using for the authentication part:

```
public function redirectToProvider()
{

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig(storage_path('app/laravel-google-analytics/service-account-credentials.json'));
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/public/authhh/google/callback');

    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);
    $client->addScope("email");
    $client->addScope("profile");
    $client->setAccessType("offline");

    $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
    return redirect($auth_url);

}


public function handleProviderCallback()
{


    // Handle authorization flow from the server.
    if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
        return redirect('auth/google');
    } else {


        // Authenticate the client, and get required informations.
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setAuthConfig(storage_path('app/laravel-google-analytics/service-account-credentials.json'));
        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);

        // Store the tokens in the session.
        Session::put('token', $client->getAccessToken());

        File::put(storage_path('app/laravel-google-analytics/google_token.json'),json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));

        $service = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
        $userInfo = $service->userinfo->get();

        $user = User::where('googleID', $userInfo->id)->first();

        //dd($client->getRefreshToken());

        // If no match, update the current user.
        if(!$user) {
            $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
            $user->google_name = $userInfo->name;
            $user->googleID = $userInfo->id;
            $user->google_email = $userInfo->email;
            $user->refreshToken = $client->getRefreshToken();
            $user->code = $_GET['code'];
            $user->update();
        }

        Auth::login($user);
        return redirect('/');
    }

}
```

Then for listing the profiles under the authenticated analytics account I use:

```
public function viewUserSettings(){

    $accountsObjects = [];

    if(Auth::user()->googleID) {
        $this->client = $this->AuthenticateCurrentClient();
        $this->analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($this->client);

        $accountsObjects = $this->GetAccounts();
    }

    return view('user.user_settings', compact('accountsObjects'));

}
```

These 2 are the AuthenticateCurrentClient() and GetAccounts() methods:

```
public function AuthenticateCurrentClient(){

    $this->user = Auth::user();
    $token = Session::get('token');

    if(empty($token)){

        $token = json_decode(File::get(storage_path('app/laravel-google-analytics/google_token.json')),true);

        Session::put('token', $token);
    }

    $client = new Google_Client();

    $client->setAuthConfig(storage_path('app/laravel-google-analytics/service-account-credentials.json'));
    $client->setAccessToken($token);
    $client->authenticate($this->user->code);
    return $client;

}

public function GetAccounts(){

    try {
        $accountsObject = $this->analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();
        $accounts = $accountsObject->getItems();

        return $accounts;

    } catch (apiServiceException $e) {
        print 'There was an Analytics API service error '
            . $e->getCode() . ':' . $e->getMessage();

    } catch (apiException $e) {
        print 'There was a general API error '
            . $e->getCode() . ':' . $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

And on my user_settings view I simply have a foreach loop that populates a dropdown select with the profiles:

```
<select name="analytics-profile" class="form-control">

                        @foreach($accountsObjects as $key=>$accountObject)
                            <option id="{{$accountObject->id}}">{{$accountObject->name}}</option>
                        @endforeach

                    </select>
```

The package I've installed through composer for this api is: "google/apiclient": "^2.0".

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: When you say "fetching the right data for the selected profile", what is the right data? Meaning which table does it come from? And is there a `profiles`  table when you say selected profile or is this the `users` table? And in what way do you want to return the data?

Comment: By fetching the right data I meant info like unique users or sessions for the  past 30 days for instance etc. When the user selects a profile from that dropdown the id which is {{$accountObject->id}} will be saved on his account and I'm thinking that based on that id the info for it could be fetched from analytics?

Comment: In your controller do you have a show() method? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers

Comment: On the controller that does all the analytics stuff I don't have a show() method.

Comment: After the user chooses from select what happens next or what do you want to happen next?

Comment: I haven't implemented it yet, but in theory when he selects an option from the select dropdown the id of the selected analytics profile will be saved on his user database entry and then whenever I'm on the dashboard for instance I'll have to fetch the analytics data for that saved profile id which is my issue right now because I do not know how to use the analytics api for fetching data.